# Does Linux unmount the root partition when the partition is about 80% full?

Tags: partition, root, knoppix

**Summary**

Linux seems to be unmounting the root partition, `/dev/sda6`. I noticed that `sda6`
is about 80% full. Does Linux unmount this root partition when it gets 80% full,
to stop you adding more files?

The unmounted `/dev/sda6` seems to be preventing me from accessing `/media/sda7`,
where I have many video files. The output below shows "/dev/sda7 /media/sda7" as
unmounted. However, SOMETIMES "mount" does show it to be mounted (but /dev/sda6
as unmounted).

Could you suggest a fix please?

My system is Knoppix on hard disc (effectively Debian).

**Full Details**

Following shows `/etc/fstab` and `mount` command output.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab  
\# DEFAULT BASE FSTAB, UNCONFIGURED  
proc       /proc         proc       noauto             0 0  
sysfs      /sys          sysfs      noauto             0 0  
/dev/sda6 / reiserfs relatime 0 0  
/dev/sda5 none swap defaults 0 0  
\# Added by KNOPPIX  
   noauto,users,exec 0 0  
\# Added by KNOPPIX  
/dev/sda7 /media/sda7 reiserfs noauto,users,exec 0 0  
\# Added by KNOPPIX  
/dev/sr0 /media/sr0 auto noauto,users,exec 0 0  
\# Added by KNOPPIX  
/dev/sda3 /media/sda3 ntfs noauto,users,exec,umask=000,uid=knoppix,gid=knoppix 0
0  
\# Added by KNOPPIX  
/dev/sda2 /media/sda2 ntfs noauto,users,exec,umask=000,uid=knoppix,gid=knoppix 0
0  
\# Added by KNOPPIX  
/dev/sda1 /media/sda1 ntfs noauto,users,exec,umask=000,uid=knoppix,gid=knoppix 0
0  

$ mount  
/dev/root on / type reiserfs (rw,relatime)  
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)  
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)  
usbfs on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw,relatime)  
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=2097152k)  
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=20480k)  
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=2097152k)  
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=1777)  
ramfs on /mnt/JG-ramdisc type ramfs (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: You say the output shows `/dev/sda7` is mounted.  Where does it show that?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134342/why-wont-my-system-now-show-the-directories-and-files-in-media-sda7

Comment: BTW: You're currently asking using multiple "unregistered" accounts. Registering would let you keep all your questions under one account, which at minimum would help you keep track of them.

Comment: Hmmm....why continue to use reiserfs?  This is old and basically no longer support.  Why not switch to something like ext4?

Comment: No, a partition doesn't get unmounted when it gets 80% full. That would waste the remaining 20%. The partition doesn't get unmounted when it gets 100% full either — you could still read or remove files from it. I don't understand why you think the partition being 80% full has anything to do with whatever problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **NO**. In one of my systems I have the root partition to 100% utilization. Linux doesn't *unmount* root partitons.

```
[root@xxx ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        39G   37G  4.5M 100% /
tmpfs           934M  232K  933M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       194M   56M  129M  31% /boot
/dev/sda5       877G  160G  673G  20% /home
```

Answer (score 2):

Your root partition is mounted in your output as `/dev/root` rather than as `sda6`.  This distinction is inconsequential.   Your partition is not being unmounted, as unmounting a partition is not possible until all child mounts are first unmounted.  E.g. in your setup you could not umount `/` without first unmounting `/home` and `/boot`, and were you able to do so you would lose access to all commands and things would just stop working.

In response to your 80% usage question, no.  In most linux filesystems the last 5% of the space is reserved for the superuser, so normal users cannot fill up a device.  This is the method that is used to prevent users from adding more files, though root can take the partition to 100% usage.